# MySQL - INNER JOIN to another server

Tags: php, mysql, join, cloud, inner-join

I have a question, how to INNER JOIN two tables between two Database server...

If INNER JOIN in one server is okay, but how about two ?

Any idea ?...

Comment: Not sure if this is possible in pure SQL.

Comment: Have you tried this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2132654/querying-multiple-databases-at-once ?

Comment: @Leandro Barreto - That question is for fixing Multiple database and not for multiple/two database SERVER ...

Comment: Go read up on the federated engine for mysql.

Answer (score 0):

You can join tables from multiple servers you can do it using Spider storage engine check this link http://spiderformysql.com/product.html

Comment: how you are going to query in PHP? you must have to use mysql and this is the best way to query multiple  databases located on different servers

Answer (score 0):

You can’t use a standard InnoDB storage engine for your use case. The best way to accommodate your case in the database layer, you can use Spider Storage Engine for MySQL. Otherwise, you need to JOIN in the application layer or use the data warehouse mechanism to do that.