# How to define foreign key in two different databases in MySQL and phpMyAdmin

Tags: mysql, database, phpmyadmin, foreign-key-relationship

I have a large database structure.
My hosting plan says I can have unlimited databases but each database is limited to 1 GB.

How can I define a foreign key in one database table to reference a table in another database using MySQL and phpMyAdmin?

Comment: I'm not somewhere I can test this, but I'd assume you could specify the foreign key in the `databasename`.`table name` syntax, e.g., something like: ... REFERENCES `databasename`.`table name` (column_name, ...)

Comment: You may also want to take a look at: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2132654/querying-multiple-databases-at-once

Answer (score 1):

In the upcoming phpMyAdmin 4.1 (now released as 4.1.0-alpha2), you go to Structure for a table, then Relation view. You then see a panel where you can select other databases for your foreign keys.