# SQL querying multiple schemas

Tags: sql

I am looking to run a query on several schemas in workbench. bascially, they are all symmetric , just different dates. In workbench, i can only select one of them and run the query. Is there a way to aggregate them and run the query over a selection of schemas?

EDIT:
To elaborate a bit more, I have schemas with names yyyy_mm_dd for each day. Ideally, instead of doing a union over them as suggested by Guish below, If would like a dynamic query that would be able to turn the name of the schema into a valid date and Union all of them where the date is within a defined range. Is this possible? I am using Oracle and sql workbench

Comment: There is for most DB platforms -- but they are platform specific -- what database platform?

Comment: Please provide examples of the “schemas” you are talking about, and the results you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you are using mySql workbench.

Use an `union` operator.

```
(SELECT a FROM `schema1`.`t1` )
UNION
(SELECT a FROM `schema2`.`t1`);
```

Info [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/union.html)

You can then create a view from your query.

A thread [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2132654/querying-multiple-databases-at-once) on querying multiple shema

In know [Transact-SQL](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms180026.aspx) a lot more and it is similar.

```
SELECT ProductModelID, Name
FROM Schema1.ProductModel
UNION ALL
SELECT ProductModelID, Name
FROM Schema2.ProductModel
ORDER BY Name;
```

Comment: `UNION ALL` is faster for statements like this which are guaranteed to be mutually exclusive, since `UNION` will attempt to remove duplicates (which don't exist).