# ActiveRecord one connection per request

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord

I have an application that let the user to connect in multiples environments. 
Depending of the choice of environment that the user pick, activerecord will use Database X or Y.

But when I use ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection, activerecord change the database for all users. 
I want that user 'A' use Database 'X' and user 'B' use Database 'Y' at the same time in one single application. 
Is that possible with rails?

Comment: are you using something like apartment or octopus

Comment: No, pure ActiveRecord only.

Comment: would you be opposed in looking into a gem to help out?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31770562/rails-same-model-with-multiple-databases-read-only) answer.

Based on user type (X or Y), you can establish the respective DB connection.

Or,

You can try [this](https://github.com/thiagopradi/octopus) gem.

Comment: This gem can help me.

Answer (score 0):

I am thinking that you can do something like this

you do need to declare the connection in your /config/database.rb

```
MyModel < ActiveRecord::Base
    establish_connection "other_#{session[:user_db]}"
end
```