# Php mysql, Select data from multiple databases

Tags: php, mysql, database

I need to select the same table in multiple databases

My select looks:

```
$con = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=[db1, db2, db3]", user, pass);
$atrib = $con->prepare("SELECT email, subdomainFROM users WHERE email = ?"); 
$atrib->bindParam(1, $email, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$atrib->execute();
if($atrib->rowCount() != 0) {
    //do something
} else {
    print "Not exist!";
}
$con = null;
```

I have databases in phpmyadmin

[image: Databases]

Does anyone have any solution to select from multiple databases?

Comment: Trying to implement a multi tenant structure I see

Comment: you can check this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2132654/querying-multiple-databases-at-once

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the UNION operator like this:

```
SELECT email, subdomain FROM db1.users WHERE email = ?
UNION
SELECT email, subdomain FROM db2.users WHERE email = ?
UNION
SELECT email, subdomain FROM db3.users WHERE email = ?;
```

Make sure your db connection has access to all the tables.