# How to alter same table in multiple databases in MySQL

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

I have a set of database schemas, with each one having the same set of tables.

I want to alter a table by adding a column in each one of the schemas with a single command, instead of doing it for every schema separateley.

Is that possible?

Comment: No. You could use dynamic sql and a stored procedure as suggested in William's answer; but for a one time `Alter`, that seems like a bit of overkill to me. ... and to make such an proc implementation more reusable, you'd need to devise a mechanism for identifying which tables in which schemas should get the Alter, and that handles different kinds of alters appropriately.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't quite identical to [Querying multiple databases at once](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2132654/querying-multiple-databases-at-once) but it's similar. As in the linked question, you could write a procedure:

1. Get the schema names from `information_schema.tables`
2. Create your query template
3. Loop over the schema names and for each schema sub the schema name in the query template

Comment: Could you please tell us the best solution for the above problem or the solution that you have implemented?